# Count co-occurrence of values and create data frame of count

Tags: r, for-loop, count, match

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x <- c(1,2,1,1,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
y <- c(21,22,23,21,21,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
z <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5)
dat <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I want to count how many times a value from x occurs in z and then 
take the value of y that corresponds to that row of x. I'm assuming I'll need to use a for loop or apply. 
The counts would populate a data frame or matrix with column headings corresponding to the y values.
I've looked through Stack Overflow and I've tried using which and %in% with no luck. I've also tried sum but it only looks across a row and sums matching occurrences. I want to look across all 
rows of the other column of interest (z).

The result would look like this (z as the row labels, y as column labels):

```
  21  22  23
1  2   0   1
2  0   1   0
3  0   0   0
4  1   0   0
5  0   0   0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use base R's `table`:

```
dat$x <- factor(dat$x, levels = unique(dat$z));
as.data.frame.matrix(table(dat[, 1:2]));
#  21 22 23
#1  2  0  1
#2  0  1  0
#3  0  0  0
#4  1  0  0
#5  0  0  0
```

Explanation: Turn column entries `x` into a `factor` with levels from `z`, then use `table` to count occurrences of entries `y` per `x`. The `factor(...)` command ensures that all possible values from `z` are considered in the `table`.

Comment: Crisp and tricky answer!

Comment: Thanks @MKR! This is one of those cases where the `NA`s work with you not against in keeping it concise:-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse` where we `mutate` 'x' with `levels` specified as the `unique` values of 'z', then get the `count` of ' and 'y', remove the NA elements (`na.omit`) and `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
    mutate(x = factor(x, levels = unique(z))) %>%
    count(x, y) %>% 
    na.omit %>%
    spread(y, n, fill = 0, drop = FALSE) %>%
    select(-x)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   `21`  `22`  `23`
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2.00  0     1.00
#2  0     1.00  0   
#3  0     0     0   
#4  1.00  0     0   
#5  0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine also provided the following solution:

```
library(tidyr)
dat$x <- factor(dat$x, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
reshape2::dcast(dat, x ~ y, fun.aggregate = length, drop = FALSE)
```